# two different uses of <span>: which is the best solution for accessibility?

Tags: css, accessibility, html

I want to substitute a piece of text with an image (for example, the word "call" with a phone icon) along some other text in a web page. I want this to work for normal user, without penalizing people who disable css *(or don't have css active) and blind people that cannot see images [addendum]*. Which is the better solution between the following two ones?

```html
1.     <span title="call" class="s1"><span>


2.     <span class="s1 s2">call<span>
```

with:

```css
.s1 {
    display:inline-block;
    background: url("call.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    width:24px;
}
.s2 {
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent: 30px;
}
```

P.S.: no `<img>` alternative, please.

Comment: People who disable CSS? Do people even do that? I've heard of people disabling JavaScript -- it's quite common in the corporate environment -- but not CSS.

Comment: My prefered method is wonderfully explained here : http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-image-replacement-with-pseudo-elements/

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: This is about accessibility (i.e. simplified access to technology for disabled people), in case of which disabling CSS is not uncommon... Read more about [accessible rich internet applications (ARIA)](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/)

Comment: @LukasEder actually I think it's pretty uncommon for AT users to disable CSS. They didn't even see fit to ask about it in the [2011 WebAIM survey](http://webaim.org/blog/survey-4-results/)

Comment: @steveax: Interesting. I'll have to re-read about those things and critically review our application. It looks like we've made some mistakes

Comment: Roddy, it's not often people disable CSS explicitly, no. But there are environments, where the blind and otherwise sensory impaired operate, for which your usual CSS, tailored for the screen, is meaningless. In essence, for them it doesn't do anything - widths, heights, colors, margins - irrelevant. And how many people think of say, aureal CSS sheets when thinking of CSS?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: There are also users of text-browsers, which naturally don't make any use of CSS.

Comment: @unor - Yes, but text browsers -- or screen readers -- wouldn't involve the act of *disabling* CSS, but rather the lack of support for it. The original post only indicated those who voluntarily disabled it, hence my confusion.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: Ah, I see. I know that some visually impaired users prefer to disable CSS and use a screen-magnifier on the browsers default display of web pages (because they can better read from top to bottom instead of having to scroll from left to right).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SPAN` is a very generic element, and should be used when no better markup element is suited for the purpose. In your case, the `A` (anchor) is just what you need, assuming your "call" element is something the user agent should distinguish from pure text. Even if you don't use `href`, it's still an anchor - just bind it to a mouse event with JavaScript.

Also, using background images here is misplaced. Background images are for backgrounds. In fact, user agents shouldn't even alow clicking on these as part of active user interface (only as a very secondary interaction) If it's a "Call" button you're after, use CSS `content` property instead. You are right about `img` though - that's for images that carry page content, not navigation. I.e. buttons, anchors and the like shouldn't use the `img` tag. You can also use `input` or `button`, depending on context (cannot tell from your question).

If you really want to make your pages accessible, you are on the right track, but I really think the following is a better alternative:

```
 <a class="s1" title="Call the following number">Call</a>

 .s1
 {
     content: url(call.png);
 }
```

You can adjust the size of your anchor that is marked with the `s1` class using CSS `width` and `height`. I would use an SVG instead though. If your graphic is vector, it is definitely a much better idea. Pixels are for photos and pixel-art :-)

If you want to add some text after your element, you can use CSS `:after`:

```
.s1:after
{
    content: "Call";
}
```

Comment: Be careful about adding essential content via generated content like `after`. It is not announced reliably.

Comment: `alt` on an anchor tag is not valid HTML. No assistive technology should see or pay attention to it. `title` is also not always announced.

Comment: @RyanB you are absolutely right. As for not recognizing `title` - well, one can only do so much.

Answer (score 5):

Between the two alternatives given, 2 is evidently the right answer, i.e. it is clearly less detrimental to accessibility. When CSS is off, the element reduces to the word “call”, whereas alternative 1 reduces to the empty string. There is no guarantee that some software is able to announce the value of the `title` attribute. Consider, for example, the use of a normal graphic browser in purely visual mode, with no screen reader (with e.g. settings that override page CSS and enforce large enough font suitable for the user).

Even alternative 2 is bad for accessibility. When CSS is *enabled*, the word “call” is replaced by an icon. But there is no guarantee that the user can see it at all. And there is no way to specify `alt` text for a background image as you can do for content images. Moreover, what would you use as a phone icon? Most such icons are old-style, like ☎ or ✆, and there are more and more people who never used such a device.